# change directory name in url only htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a directory in my web root projectae/project/index.php and I want to change directory name only in url but in root still have the of projectae so I want to change

```
localhost/projectae/project/index.php 
to
localhost/ae/project
```

I did some try on my htaccess but none succeed
I did try :

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /projectae/
RewriteRule ^projectae/(.*)$ /ae/$1 [L]
```

I also tried

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^pojectae/project/$ /ae/project/$1 [L]
```

I did clear cache nothing work; I did restart apache nothing work
my config file :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        <Directory /var/www/html/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        <IfModule mod_dir.c>
            DirectoryIndex index.php index.pl index.cgi index.html index.xhtml index.htm
        </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your description suggests that you want to rewrite the other way round:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?ae/(.*)$ /projectae/$1 [L]
```

A typical combination would be to combine rules for redirection and rewriting:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?projectae/(.*)$ /ae/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/?ae/(.*)$ /projectae/$1 [L]
```

Those rules will work likewise in the http servers central host configuration or in a distributed configuration file (".htaccess" style file). If you really have to use such a distributed file then take care that it's consideration is enabled in your host configuration (see the documentation for the `AllowOverride` directive) and that above rule is placed in such a file inside the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder of the http host.

Comment: I add apache config to my question; I tried your solution but that doesn't work

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean _exactly_ ? What happens if you make a test request? What response do you get and what do you see in your http server's error log file?

Comment: Where did you place that configuration file? Did you make sure it is readable for the http server process?

Comment: And a hint: no need to clear your browser cache. Instead always open a fresh anonymous browser window. Much easier and more reliable.

Comment: Nothing working

Comment: Really? To my question "What does "doesn't work" mean exactly ?" you respond "Nothing working"? Without answering _any_ of the questions I asked? Really?

Comment: the config file is /etc/apache2/site-enable/000-default.conf and .htaccess is in root